# Launch Program from IE

Tags: internet-explorer, external, launch

Is it possible to launch a program from an anchor in IE?  For example, iTunes had links like itms:blahblah that would open up iTunes and go directly to the appropriate page.  If so, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429770/how-to-make-webkit-or-ie-call-your-application-net-from-html-page-opened-in-br/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking purely from the browser, you can't register your own "protocol"... the thing is that when you installed iTunes, it registered the `itms` protocol so that any link that looks like this:

```
<a href="itms://something.mp3">click me</a>
```

Would open up the iTunes app. You can't do that (without running your own executable *first* which registers your custom protocol with the computer), but, what you can do is make a link to a file on our local computer... example:

```
<a href="file://c:/windows/notepad.exe">Launch Notepad</a>
```

I, of course, am assuming that you're making a simple HTML page that is meant for your own internal use (or on your companies internal network) to launch *known* programs from your computer.

Comment: Yeah it's for launching internal programs inside a company's internal network. No spam, virus or spyware intentions, I assure you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not without help. Your protocol has to be registered on the user's computer, which can be done via [ftype](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftype.mspx?mfr=true). I'd assume that what you're seeing is the product of the iTunes installer registering `itms`. If you type `ftype itms` at the command line, you're likely to get something like `itms=C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe /url "%1"`.

That is to say, no, you can't do it just from inside the browser, that would be a terrible, horrible, no-good, very-bad security hole.