# Making my application open/called from a browser with a custom protocol

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im making a small application that opens my own files that contains log data. I have a log viewer for these files but would like to link to them from my intranet. Im looking to create an url that looks like this:

```
log://log/id
```

Where log and id is the path to the file from the net to open. How do I accomplish this. Should the changes be in my application or in the IIS that serves the page (and thus the link)?

cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be done [fairly easily for IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx), but I am not sure about other browsers.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429770/how-to-make-webkit-or-ie-call-your-application-net-from-html-page-opened-in-br) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a custom *scheme* is probably going to require installation/registration at the OS level, for example in the registry for windows (allow user-level may suffice). For the sake of simplicity, http would probably the sensible default unless you really, ***really*** need something custom.

MSDN discusses this for windows here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx